# Video creating using "-vprofile baseline" giving error

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am padding a video using

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "pad=width=640:height=480:x=0:y=120:color=black" output.mp4`

The command is working fine. But I want to use "-vprofile baseline" to get a small size video. If I run the command

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "pad=width=640:height=480:x=0:y=120:color=black -vprofile baseline" output.mp4`

It's giving an error

```
 01-07 16:35:40.494: I/process data info >>>>>>>>>>(6116): ffmpeg version git-2013-11-13-129af66 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers  built on Nov 13 2013 16:40:26 with gcc 4.4.3 (GCC)  configuration: --arch=arm --target-os=linux --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --prefix=../build --sysroot=/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm --extra-cflags=' -I/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -I/Users/sunitha/Downloads/full_ffmpeg/ffmpeg-android/libmp3lame/include -DANDROID -marm -march=armv6 ' --extra-ldflags=' -L/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib -L/Users/sunitha/Downloads/full_ffmpeg/ffmpeg-android/libmp3lame/lib' --disable-debug --enable-libmp3lame --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --enable-avfilter --enable-decoders --enable-demuxers --enable-encoders --enable-filters --enable-indevs --enable-network --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-swscale --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree  libavutil      52. 39.100 / 52. 39.100  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102  libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100  libavfilter     3. 80.100 /  3. 80.100  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100Unrecognized option 'vprofile baseline'.Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
    01-07 16:35:40.494: I/exit code >>>>>>>>..(6116): 1
    01-07 16:35:40.494: I/exit code >>>>>>>>..(6116): 1
```

The error is:

```
Unrecognized option 'vprofile baseline'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Baseline profile has to do with **hardware capability**, not **size**. But if you need to use it, don't use inside filter. Also it is incompatible with lossless encoding. So try:

```
ffmpeg -i input -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 23 \
-profile:v baseline output.mp4
```

If your filter section is otherwise working fine, use it separately:

```
ffmpeg -i input -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-vf "pad=width=640:height=480:x=0:y=120:color=black" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 \
-profile:v baseline output.mp4
```

This will encode audio to AAC using the `libfaac` or `libfdk_aac` encoders if your ffmpeg was compiled with them. If you don't have these, you can use the built-in `aac` encoder with the options `-c:a aac -strict -2`. See the [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for more info.

You could also use `-c:a copy` to [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio and that should not hurt the video encoding. And of course the choice of video quality (`-crf`) or video bitrate (`-b:v` instead of `-crf`) is up to you as well. See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more info.

Comment: Hi rajib I am getting error as unrecognized options "an -pix_fmt yuv420 error splitting the argument list". If you do not get this please let me know, how to post complete log cat error while replying?

Comment: Where exactly are you putting in the double quotes? They are needed only for the video filter section. And it should be `yuv420p`. Remeber the `p`.